# Xamarin IntentService started by HardwareButton

Tags: c#, android, service, xamarin, intentservice

I tried now for days to get this running, without any success.

I'm trying to react on an hardwarebutton from my handheld via the functions of their specific SDK (it's a Panasonic Toughpad). I'm generating this code in Xamarin and i got one sample of the SDK in Java.

Here's my Code:

First of all the Service itself.
Serviceclass:

```
[Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.panasonic.toughpad.android.api.appbutton.intent.APPBUTTON" } )]
    class ButtonIntentService : IntentService
    {
        public ButtonIntentService() :base("ButtonIntentHandlerThread"){ }

        protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            if (!intent.Action.Equals(AppButtonManager.ActionAppbutton))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (ButtonTestFragment.getInstance() !=null)
            {
                ButtonTestFragment.getInstance().updateButtonState(intent);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

Here's the code snipped of the AndroidManifest.
AndroidManifest:

```
    <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name="com.SoftwareTestXamarin.Droid.ButtonIntentService"
        android:label="button api Sample"
        android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.panasonic.toughpad.android.api.appbutton.intent.APPBUTTON"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I'm new in this API connecting things. In my thoughts the Intent should now hear on the `HandheldButtons` via the filter. So when I click the `AppButton` of my Handheld it should start the `IntentServices` Functions?!? Or am I wrong? 
In my Opinion they are doing the same in their Java Sample.

Code:

Serviceclass:

```
public class ButtonIntentService extends IntentService {

    public ButtonIntentService() {
        super("Button Intent Handler Thread");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (!intent.getAction().equals(AppButtonManager.ACTION_APPBUTTON)) {
            // Ignore..
            return;
        }

        if (ButtonTestFragment.getInstance() != null) {
            ButtonTestFragment.getInstance().updateButtonState(intent);
        }

    }
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<service
            android:name="com.panasonic.toughpad.android.sample.buttons.ButtonIntentService"
            android:label="@string/lbl_button_service"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.panasonic.toughpad.android.api.appbutton.intent.APPBUTTON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

> ----UPDATE 04.08----

Just for your information. I also tried to get the event from the `APPBUTTON` with a `BroadcastReceiver` and let it start the `IntentService` without any success. Here are the added Code Snippets:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.panasonic.toughpad.android.api.appbutton.intent.APPBUTTON" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
    class ButtonReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var serviceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(ButtonIntentService));
            serviceIntent.PutExtras(intent);
            context.StartService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
```

Snippet of AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver android:name="ButtonReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.panasonic.toughpad.android.api.appbutton.intent.APPBUTTON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: A couple things to check since I do not see it in your code: 1) Are the proper permissions given in your Xamarin application compared to the sample app? (Can you link to the sample app as well?)

2) Ensure that this custom intent can be broadcasted and then received properly. Use `SendBroadcast(Intent)` to test this locally in your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got now a solution for this problem.

You have to check if you have the control of the device buttons. If not, you have to choose the `IntentService` for the buttons via a menue. After selecting your application the service will work. 
This simple Check will handle the problems with the `IntentService`:

```
if (!AppButtonManager.HasButtonControl)
                {
                    Intent reconfigureApp = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
                    reconfigureApp.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryLauncher);
                    reconfigureApp.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                    reconfigureApp.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.panasonic.toughpad.android.service",
                                                              "com.panasonic.toughpad.android.appbuttondelegator.ConfigActivity"));
                    activity.StartActivity(reconfigureApp);
                }
```

You don't need the Broadcast-Service with this solution. The IntentService itself is enough.